Reference the intended recipient in postfix custom bounce template
I'm running a mailserver on an Ubuntu 24 machine with Postfix(v3.8.6), Dovecot and Amavis working together to form a mail system for multiple domains. The postmaster for the main domain of the mailserver sends out bounce messages for all failed messages regardless of the domain. This means if someone emails nobody@example5.com, they would get a bounce message from @example1.com and may be confused about what email they sent failed. I want to be able to reference the address they sent an email to in the bounce message or the domain they tried to reach. It seems I can only use main.cf variables in the template, which is no good because main.cf variables don't update to the specifics of the email that has failed. The custom templates are at /bounce.cf and are fully working, but I can't reference the email they attempted to send to.
Summary

Postfix custom bounce template
I want to reference ($) the specific address the user tried to email
I can't find the variable to support this

